# iOS Layout Constraints | Width anchor vs leading and trailing anchors

Tags: ios, autolayout

I haven’t been using AutoLayout constraints for long, so I haven’t fully grasp some of its inner workings.

In particular, are there times I can use the `widthAnchor` and the `leading` **and** `trailing` anchors interchangeably, and others that I need all 3? Or, is valid to use the `widthAnchor` with the `leadingAnchor` **or** the `trailingAnchor`?

To sum up my question, is the combination of the `leading` and `trailing` anchors just defining the width and the X axis position of a view, just as the `widthAnchor` with the `leadingAnchor`  would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the auto layout needs at least two constraints for views having an intrinsic size and at least four for views without having an intrinsic size. Let's say your view has an intrinsic size(eg. UITextView), it's just enough to constraint the x-axis and y axis. If you wish, you can specify the fixed size with width anchor and height anchor or dynamic size with constraining top, bottom, leading, trailing anchors based on the screen size but this is just optional. If your view doesn't have an intrinsic content size(eg. UIImageView), you need to specify at least one x-axis, one y-axis and width and height anchor or constraint leading, trailing, top and bottom anchors. The point is if you have the leading and trailing anchors, you don't need to specify width anchor and vice versa. Now, you get the idea. If you constraint top and bottom anchor, you shouldn't add height anchor to avoid conflicts.

Comment: What if I have say a label inside a view, and I want both the label and the view to grow dynamically, based on the label's text? All I need, is to set leading, trailing, top and bottom anchors for the label?

Comment: Since the UIView doesn't have an intrinsic content size, it might need some tweak. You first need to constraint the view to the maximum width and height anchor that you could allow and set the top, leading, trailing and bottom anchor of the label to that view. In this way, the label will grow dynamically till it reaches the view's width and height.

Comment: The another possible way is you set the leading and top anchor or trailing and bottom anchor of the label first and then set the view's width, height, leading and top anchor equal to the label.